# Continuous Acquisition of Data from Sensor Attached to Android (Thread, ASync Task, Service)

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have connected one sensor with `Android Phone`. The Sensor measures the response and display the respective result on the app. I tried to use the `Java Timer` but now planning to move to `Thread`.

While in continuous mode, the app will be totally disable and don't need any user attraction. User need to set some pre-acquisition setting and then press the start button. After starting this button, the `main GUI` will be updated continuously but while the operation is going, user can't interact with the app. User need to press that "start" button again to stop the app. Start button will act as stop button at this moment.

I am new to Android so i studied on internet and found that instead of `thread`, `Asyntask` is better option. And then someone also mentioned that `Service` can be better too for running long processes or `Concurrent`. I want my app to run for a long time without halting or memory leak.

What do you think is better in my case? and in the meantime, i tried to use `AsyncTask`.

Here is my code using `AsynTask`. I want this code to run continuously and update the UI thread. `UI` has a graph which will be updated with the data from background.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); //This button will start and stop the app.
button.setOnClickListener(addOnButtonClick(button));
}
```

//From main a button will be pressed and then from button signal, Aysnctask will be called. I just implemented the `doInBackground` funtion.

```
 View.OnClickListener addOnButtonClick(final Button button){
        return  new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                new AsyncTaskActivity().doInBackground();
//Here i want to add one flag, which will be activated as 'true`when the
//button will be pressed once and `fasle` when the button will be pressed //second time. 
//True-> activity run, false ->activity stop.
                }
            };
        }

 public class AsyncTaskActivity extends AsyncTask<Void , Void, Void>{


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){


                nativeData = getDatafromsensor(); //Data from native.

                DataPoint[] data = new DataPoint[Size];
                for (int i=0; i<Size; i++) {
                    double x = i;
                    double y = nativeData[i];
                    DataPoint v = new DataPoint(x, y);
                    data[i] = v;
                    }
                }
                series.resetData(data);
            }
return null;
        }
```

Comment: I think you need to be a little bit more specific in what you're looking for. What's the actual question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `Service` might be the way to go long-term, but here's how you can get going with `AsyncTask`.

You should read the "Usage" section of [AsyncTask docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) very carefully so you understand the interaction between the UI thread methods and the background thread methods.  In your `onClick()` method, you are calling `doInBackground()` directly, and that's a no-no.  You call `execute()` and `doInBackground()` is invoked on a different thread as a result.

`AsyncTask` has a way to update progress.  It's meant to be used to update (for example) a progress bar (which has to be done from the UI thread) while the background thread is still running.  You can actually use this to achieve your goal.

Here is some example code:

Make a subclass of `AsyncTask` to run your data capture thread:

```
public class SensorTask extends AsyncTask<Void, List<Double>, Void> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // runs on the UI thread
        // TODO set up your UI for data acquisition
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // TODO initialize sensor for acquisition

        while (! isCancelled()) {

            nativeData = getDatafromsensor(); //Data from native.
            List<Double> sensorData = new ArrayList<Double>();

            for (int i = 0; i < nativeData.length; i++) {
                sensorData.add(new Double(nativeData[i]);
            }
            publishProgress(sensorData);  // this invokes onProgressUpdate on UI thread
            Thread.sleep(DELAY_TIME);  // if you need to
        }

        // TODO sensor cleanup
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(List<Double>... values) {
        // runs on the UI thread
        // TODO update your UI with the sensor data
    }

    protected void onCancelled(Void result) {
        // runs on the UI thread
        // TODO update UI for acquisition complete
    }

}
```

And here's how you kick it off:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // you need to keep a reference to the task so you can cancel it later
        if (mSensorTask != null) {
            // task already exists -- if running, stop it
            mSensorTask.cancel(false);
            mSensorTask = null;
        } else {
            // task doesn't exist -- make a new task and start it
            mSensorTask = new SensorTask();
            mSensorTask.execute();    
            // this will make doInBackground() run on background thread
        }

    };
```

And this is important: Make sure you cancel the task in the activity's `onPause()` method so the thread only runs when the Activity is current.

---

EDIT: 
Using a global array has the advantage of eliminating extra object allocations.  Just make sure you synchronize access to the data array.
Here's another way to code the `AsyncTask` for using a global array:

```
public class SensorTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // runs on the UI thread
        // TODO set up your UI for data acquisition
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // TODO initialize sensor for acquisition

        while (! isCancelled()) {

            synchronized (nativeData) {
                nativeData = getDatafromsensor(); // Data from native.
            }
            publishProgress(null);  // this invokes onProgressUpdate on UI thread
            Thread.sleep(DELAY_TIME);  // if you need to
        }

        // TODO sensor cleanup
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        // runs on the UI thread
        synchronized (nativeData) {
            // TODO update your UI with the sensor data
        }
    }

    protected void onCancelled(Void result) {
        // runs on the UI thread
        // TODO update UI for acquisition complete
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed reply and i applied the method also. i need little more help. The method in background returns `double array`. But the argument in `onProcessUpdate` is `Double`. Can you tell me the specific changes in the above code. and also instead of `onPause`, i cancelled the task in `onStop` of main activity as `mSensorTask.cancel(true)`. Will this work?

Comment: also one more confusion. You said on 5th line that `You call execute() and doInBackground() is invoked on a different thread as a result.` But i read some articles which state clearly that atleast `doInBackground()` needed necessary. So if only define `doInBackground()`, will that process don't start on new thread?

Comment: I wondered about that `double[]` array.  I've updated the example code to closer reflect what you need.  `onStop()` may work for cancelling.  I just chose `onPause()` to shut down the thread and stop updating the UI before the Activity starts saving state.  You just have to test your code thoroughly and make sure there's no way the `AsyncTask` can stay running if your user leaves that Activity screen.

Comment: I did a different thing. The return `double array` from native is declared as `global` variable and i just passed a dummy double value from the `doInBackground()` to the `publishprogress`. I used that global variable in `onProgressUpdate`. It's working okay. And with `onStop()`, the `Asynctask` is terminating smoothly. Any comments on the global thing?

Comment: `new AsyncTaskActivity().doInBackground();` creates a new `AsyncTaskActivity` then *calls* `doInBackground()` on the UI thread.   You always want to call `execute()`.  `doInBackground()` will be invoked on the correct thread.

Comment: The global value concerns me a little bit.  I can tweak the example code a little later for another approach (no time right now).  But please accept my answer if it helped you get your app working.  :)

Comment: I already accepted your answer. Sure, i will wait for another approach. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: i wrote one answer, but it is actually a question. Can you please look at it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used your technique and in the `pre`, i set the graphical index and initialized the conditions. In the `background` thing, i called the native function and got the data from the sensor. In the `publish` I am displaying that data in graphical form and for that i used `GraphView` library. Here is the code

```
public class AsyncTaskActivity extends AsyncTask<Void, Double, Void> {


    protected void onPreExecute() {
            viewport.setMinY(0);
            viewport.setMaxY(8000);
            viewport.setMinX(0);
            viewport.setMaxX(330);
            staticLabelsFormatter = new StaticLabelsFormatter(graph);
            staticLabelsFormatter.setHorizontalLabels(new String[]{"400", "500", "600", "730"});
            graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(staticLabelsFormatter);

        } 


    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        while (!isCancelled()) {
            synchronized (nativeData) {
            nativeData = getDatafromsensor(); // Data from native.
        }
        publishProgress(null);  // this invokes onProgressUpdate on UI thread
    }
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

///This one here
            series.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb((int) spec_data[WeightSize], (int) spec_data[WeightSize+1], (int) spec_data[WeightSize+2]));
            series.resetData(data);

    }

    protected void onCancelled(Void result) {
        Log.d("Updates", "I am In Cancelled");
        if (mSensorTask != null)
            mSensorTask.cancel(true);


    }

}
```

Issue:

The problem is that in `ProgressUpdate`, when i am setting the background color. It is flickering a lot. Like sometimes it don't show for more than 30 seconds, even though the graph is changing perfectly. Do i need to put sleep. But the why graph is changing instantly?

Comment: If your sensor is updating very rapidly, then you need to throttle the display redraws in `onProgressUpdate()`.  Here are some ideas:  Redraw the graph every, say, hundredth time through.  Track the time and only redraw when a second has passed.  I can't find javadocs for GraphView but I read from the description that there is a real-time graph.  So I don't know how GraphView works, but you might ask another question on SO with tag "android-graphview" and the developer can help you. In your question, be sure to mention how much data there is and how fast it's coming.

Comment: You might want to look at it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34011301/graphview-android-color-under-graph-flickering-issue

Comment: Also if you think the questions are valid then can you please upvote them. Thanks

Comment: @kris, i did some digging in the problem and found that it's `Async` which is creaing problem for me. I tried both method `Global Variabl` and `Local Double List`. Actually i need to lock the data in background unless the results are published on the `progress`. Because in `progress` two functions are used. One for displaying data on the Graph and one for putting color under it. Can you give me some hints that `Background thread` will wait for the progress to completely publish the data on UI? Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with Java's `synchronized` keyword and what it does?

Comment: Yes Sir, I know what is the purpose of using that `Synchronized` in the code. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: That's why I had `synchronized (nativeData)` in two places in the code, so that the sensor acquisition would wait until the graph update was done and vice versa.  My questions are: How many times per second does the sensor generate data?  Also, those RGB colors for the background, are they only a few colors like green and red, or is it like a gradient with many colors?  And how much time does the graph update take?  Knowing those things will help in figuring out a solution.

Comment: I also think you should contact the GraphView developer and ask for help.